# To find intersection of two arrays in C++

Tags: c++, stl

**Here my code :**

```
  void intersection(int input1[], int input2[], int size1, int size2) {
    unordered_map<int,int> mymap;
    for(int i=0;i<size1;i++){
        if(!mymap.count(input1[i]))
            mymap[input1[i]] = 1;
        else
            mymap[input1[i]]++;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<size2; i++){
        if(mymap.count(input2[i]) > 0){
            cout<<input2[i]<<endl;
            mymap[input2[i]]--;  //Line1
        }   
    }
}
```

I tried decreasing the "key" in "Line1" but not getting correct output. 
Sample Input:

size1:
6

array1:
2 6 8 5 4 3

size2:
7

array2:
2 2 3 4 7 4 3

Your Output:
2
2
3
4
4
3

Expected Output:
2
3
4

Comment: Where you're going wrong is not following stackoverflow.com's instructions for showing a [mre] in your question. Please [edit] your question to have a short, self-contained program that anyone can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, and run, then explain what the results are, what you believe the results should be, and why. There could be bugs somewhere else in your code that affect the results here, which are impossible to analyze unless you provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Underlying logic is correct, but syntax is wrong:

`mymap.count(x)` returns the number of time key is present.
You want `mymap[x]` (or use a `std::multi_set`).

Line1 should then be:

```
mymap[input2[i]]--;
```

In addition, your first loop (which has similar error BTW) can be simplified to:

```
std::unordered_map<int,int> mymap;
for(int i=0;i<size1;i++){
    mymap[input1[i]]++;
}
```

So final code:

```
void intersection(int input1[], int input2[], int size1, int size2) {
    std::unordered_map<int,int> mymap;
    for(int i=0;i<size1;i++){
        mymap[input1[i]]++;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<size2; i++){
        if (mymap[input2[i]] > 0){
            cout << input2[i] << endl;
            mymap[input2[i]]--;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. I edited it accordingly but it's giving wrong output (pls. refer to edited post)

Comment: Thanks to avoid to edit question in a way which invalidate existing answers.